# Showing AUCTeX command result buffer alongside current one in Emacs

Tags: emacs, auctex

I'm trying to get TeXcount to work inside Emacs with AUCTeX. According to the [TeXCount website](http://app.uio.no/ifi/texcount/faq.html#emacs), it should be possible to use the following to run `texcount` on the current buffer:

```
(require 'tex)
(add-to-list 'TeX-command-list
      (list "TeXcount" "texcount %s.tex" 'TeX-run-command nil t))
```

When I run this, a buffer is created with the results, but the buffer does not open in the current window and is instead buried in the buffer list where I have to then go and look for it. How can I get AucTeX to open the buffer next to the one I'm currently looking at?

Comment: Try to use `TeX-run-compile` instead of `TeX-run-command`

Comment: I discovered that the buffer is shown if `TeX-show-compilation` is set to `t`, but this also results in the compilation window for latex showing up as well, which I don't care about. I suppose that this problem requires some sort of additional logic to solve.

Comment: If `TeX-show-compilation` is set to `t` then `TeX-run-command` shows buffer named `*path/file output*`. `TeX-run-compile` shows buffer named `*compilation*` independently of variable `TeX-show-compilation`.